# instead of matching, getting the same url in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Scraping several fields from this website  with the following spider. The problem I encounter is that urls I'm getting are the ones, which apply to all 16 models on the page , then again another url, again applying to 16 models. I just can't establish the problem with url xpath. Could you point out where do I have a flaw in the url xpath? 
Thanks.
p.s. Other fields are working just fine and are matching. 
Missing price fields are out of stock models.

```
class ZoomSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "zoom2"
allowed_domains = ["zoomer.ge"]
start_urls = [
    "http://zoomer.ge/index.php?cid=35&act=search&category=1&search_type=mobile"
]

rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index.php\?cid=35&act=search&category=1&search_type=mobile&page=\d*", )) 
        , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)


def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productContainer"]/div[5]/div[@class="productListContainer"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
        item = ZoomerItem()
            url = sel.xpath('//div[@class="productListImage"]/a/@href').extract()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('div[3]/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('div[@class="productListPrice"]/div/text()').extract()
            item["model"] = t.xpath('div[3]/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')[0].strip()
            item["url"] = urljoin("http://zoomer.ge", url[0])

            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use relative xpaths, with your xpath you are always getting first link on each page you should use:

```
t.xpath('.//div[@class="productListImage"]/a/@href').extract()
```

note the dot there at the beginning. Xpaths should be relative to specific selector, in your case this is 't' in for loop.

This is pretty common mistake, [it's described in scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths)

Comment: Tried that one as well, results are same.

Comment: are you using t selector?

Comment: Oh my god...stupid me :D.
Thank you so much. Was banging my head on keyboard.